# Automatically Generate UML Instance Diagrams in NetBeans

Tags: java, object, netbeans, uml, diagram

Is there any way to automatically generate an Instance Diagram of my project in NetBeans? 
Something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/015xT.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKrNA.png

I managed to generate the class UML and the hierarchy diagram, but the instance diagram.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: What did you use to generate the class diagram, and what version of NetBeans?

Comment: Visual Paradigam, Im using the latest version of Netbeans. I have to tell you that its a bit tricky to generate them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. NetBeans [supports](http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u) class diagram automatic creation, but automatic creation of instance diagrams is possible only analyzing the run of the application. It is absolutely useless - you'll have too MANY diagrams and elements. And object diagrams (that is their correct name, not instance ones) are created only for some specific instances and can be done by hand.